# Combinations: Numbers 1 thru 22, totals of 4 number non-repeating

Tags: combinations

If we have a lottery drawing with numbers 1 thru 22 in a pool. We have to draw four numbers. The total number of 4 number combinations is 7,315.

Now the hard part, assume that you want to only keep combinations where no more than 2 out of 4 are the same.

For example, you draw the combination 1,2,3,4 then 1,2,3,5 or 2,3,4,6 are no good. The next valid combinations is 1,2,5,6 because no three numbers are the same as in 1,2,3,4.

How can I pull out all the combinations from 1,2,3,4 to 19,20,21,22 that only have two same numbers from all other combinations.

Or what is the formula to find out how many valid combinations there are?

Here are the first few valid combinations.
(1,2,3,4):(1,2,5,6):(1,2,7,8):(1,2,9,10):(1,2,11,12):(1,2,13,14)...

Thank you for any help in advance,
DJ

Comment: No, it is not. This has to do with lottery probabilities.

Comment: I think you're off on your estimate of combinations. If we look at the combinations for each drawing. `21 x 20 x 19 x 18 = 143,640` not `7,315`.

Comment: The equation I used is (n!)/((r!)(n-r)!) where n=22 and r=4

Comment: Hmmm... I just went and generated every unique set for four digits between 1-22 and I came out with `143,640`. I'm posting my code right now.

Comment: I used the MATLAB function combntns(set,subset)
http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/map/ref/combntns.html

Comment: David's "n choose k" formula correct in an unordered set (1,2,3,4 is the same as 4,3,2,1) - Michael is correct in an ordered set (1,2,3,4 and 4,3,2,1 are different)..

Comment: @MikeChristensen - Thanks for the clarification between our methods. It gave me a good idea for fixing my generation code.

Comment: My combinations are correct but the trouble I have is pulling out combinations where no more than 2 out of 4 numbers are the same. I was thinking maybe representing every number from 1 to 22 with a letter would be easier for the computer to compare

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I just can't code to save my life.

Comment: @DavidJones - Yea, I can't think of a good way to do that besides brute force, but you might wander over to math.stackexchange.com and ask those guys..  Some super smart people on that one..

Comment: Thank you. I'll post it there too. Not an easy question to explain.

Comment: @DavidJones The code below generates the correct number of combinations now. I'm getting `263` answers.

Comment: Michael, how come you made it to 23? Also, what program should I run this in?

Comment: I found out through testing that python ranges operate unusually. They include the left side value but exclude the right side value. To use this you can save it as a text file with a .py extension (I called it `test.py` on my machine) and run it using `python test.py` (or whatever you name it on your machine).

Comment: Thank you so much. I will give it a try. I also posted the question on math.stackexchange in hopes of getting a formula that tells us the number of correct combinations so we apply it to other sets.

Comment: @DavidJones No problem. If you don't mind maybe clicking the plus arrow on the solution (after you make sure it works) and setting it as the answer it'd be much appreciated. :) I'm also going to add my sort code (since the sets are unordered it can be harder to see the correctness) so that you'll get the answer in the ordered list you're expecting.

Comment: It worked! Michael, I'm not sure where the "plus arrow" is but I did make the check mark green. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly inelegant brute force method.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from sets import Set

setlist = []

# Generate all sets
# Sets are guaranteed to have only unique numbers
# Note: Python ranges are inclusive on the left but exclusive on the right
for first in range(1,23):
  for second in range(first+1,23):
    for third in range(second+1,23):
      for fourth in range(third+1,23):
        possible = Set([first, second, third, fourth])
        # Only take sets of 4 digits
        if len(possible) == 4:
          setlist.append(possible)

# Print the total number of combinations
print len(setlist)

answers = []
for aset in setlist:
  # Append the first answer automatically
  if len(answers) == 0:
     answers.append(aset)

  ok = True
  #Check against all our previous answers
  for answer in answers:
    # We have more than two intersecting values, this is not an answer
    if (len(answer.intersection(aset)) > 2):
      ok = False
      break;

  # If our answer is ok
  if ok:
    answers.append(aset)

# Clean up our answers and sort them all
clean = []
for answer in answers:
  temp = list(answer)
  temp.sort()
  clean.append(temp)
# Print the clean answers
print clean


# Print the total
print len(answers)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a combinatorial block design. The number of elements in the base set is 22, while the number of elements in each block is 4. Furthermore, the blocks must have the property that no triple (e.g., {1,2,3}) appears in more than one block, which is a more precise way of saying "you want to only keep combinations where only 2 out of 4 are the same".

To get an upper bound on the number of blocks, first consider a single block (e.g., {1,2,3,4}). In that block there are four triples: {1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {1,3,4}, and {2,3,4}. The total number of triples of 22 elements is <sub>22</sub>C<sub>3</sub> = 22x21x20/(3x2x1) = 1540. Since each block contains 4 triples, the maximum number of blocks is 1540/4 = 385. That's not to say that it is possible to find 385 blocks, but we shall see in a moment.

Note that generating a design by a "greedy" method, as another poster has attempted, is almost certainly doomed to failure. Choices at an early point in the greedy algorithm will negatively impact the number of choices later, which will likely lead to an impasse before 385 blocks have been found.

If you find a block design where every triple occurs *exactly* once, rather than at most once, you have found a 3-(22,4,1) block design. 3 is for triples, 22 is the number of base elements, 4 is the size of the blocks, and 1 is the number of times each triple occurs. Such a block design is also known as a Steiner quadruple system.

Some academic work has been done on Steiner quadruple systems. In particular, Hanani, H. "On Quadruple Systems." Canad. J. Math. 12, 145-157, 1960 shows that a quadruple system is possible if and only if the number of elements is congruent to 2 or 4 mod 6. Since 22 is congruent to 4 mod 6, there is a quadruple system in your case, so it is possible to find a full set of 385 blocks.

Hanani's paper gives an explicit construction, too, which is too complicated to describe here, but fortunately has been implemented in the FOSS Sage system. You can download Sage for free and just run `print designs.steiner_quadruple_system(22)` to obtain a list of the 385 blocks. Note that numbering starts at 0, so if you want your numbers to go from 1 to 22 just add 1 to each number, and if you want a block with four consecutive numbers other than {1,2,3,4} you can ask for a renumbering (or just do it yourself by adding k mod 22 to every number in the design).

Here are the blocks supplied by Sage:

```
blocks=[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 4, 5],
[0, 1, 6, 21], [0, 1, 7, 8], [0, 1, 9, 17], [0, 1, 10, 16], [0, 1, 11,
19], [0, 1, 12, 18], [0, 1, 13, 20], [0, 1, 14, 15], [0, 2, 4, 6], [0,
2, 5, 21], [0, 2, 7, 9], [0, 2, 8, 17], [0, 2, 10, 15], [0, 2, 11, 20],
[0, 2, 12, 19], [0, 2, 13, 18], [0, 2, 14, 16], [0, 3, 4, 21], [0, 3, 5,
6], [0, 3, 7, 10], [0, 3, 8, 16], [0, 3, 9, 15], [0, 3, 11, 18], [0, 3,
12, 20], [0, 3, 13, 19], [0, 3, 14, 17], [0, 4, 7, 11], [0, 4, 8, 19],
[0, 4, 9, 20], [0, 4, 10, 17], [0, 4, 12, 15], [0, 4, 13, 16], [0, 4,
14, 18], [0, 5, 7, 12], [0, 5, 8, 18], [0, 5, 9, 16], [0, 5, 10, 20],
[0, 5, 11, 15], [0, 5, 13, 17], [0, 5, 14, 19], [0, 6, 7, 13], [0, 6, 8,
15], [0, 6, 9, 18], [0, 6, 10, 19], [0, 6, 11, 16], [0, 6, 12, 17], [0,
6, 14, 20], [0, 7, 14, 21], [0, 7, 15, 20], [0, 7, 16, 19], [0, 7, 17,
18], [0, 8, 9, 10], [0, 8, 11, 12], [0, 8, 13, 14], [0, 8, 20, 21], [0,
9, 11, 13], [0, 9, 12, 14], [0, 9, 19, 21], [0, 10, 11, 14], [0, 10, 12,
13], [0, 10, 18, 21], [0, 11, 17, 21], [0, 12, 16, 21], [0, 13, 15, 21],
[0, 15, 16, 17], [0, 15, 18, 19], [0, 16, 18, 20], [0, 17, 19, 20], [1,
2, 4, 21], [1, 2, 5, 6], [1, 2, 7, 17], [1, 2, 8, 9], [1, 2, 10, 14],
[1, 2, 11, 18], [1, 2, 12, 20], [1, 2, 13, 19], [1, 2, 15, 16], [1, 3,
4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 21], [1, 3, 7, 16], [1, 3, 8, 10], [1, 3, 9, 14], [1,
3, 11, 20], [1, 3, 12, 19], [1, 3, 13, 18], [1, 3, 15, 17], [1, 4, 7,
19], [1, 4, 8, 11], [1, 4, 9, 16], [1, 4, 10, 20], [1, 4, 12, 14], [1,
4, 13, 17], [1, 4, 15, 18], [1, 5, 7, 18], [1, 5, 8, 12], [1, 5, 9, 20],
[1, 5, 10, 17], [1, 5, 11, 14], [1, 5, 13, 16], [1, 5, 15, 19], [1, 6,
7, 14], [1, 6, 8, 13], [1, 6, 9, 19], [1, 6, 10, 18], [1, 6, 11, 17],
[1, 6, 12, 16], [1, 6, 15, 20], [1, 7, 9, 10], [1, 7, 11, 12], [1, 7,
13, 15], [1, 7, 20, 21], [1, 8, 14, 20], [1, 8, 15, 21], [1, 8, 16, 18],
[1, 8, 17, 19], [1, 9, 11, 15], [1, 9, 12, 13], [1, 9, 18, 21], [1, 10,
11, 13], [1, 10, 12, 15], [1, 10, 19, 21], [1, 11, 16, 21], [1, 12, 17,
21], [1, 13, 14, 21], [1, 14, 16, 17], [1, 14, 18, 19], [1, 16, 19, 20],
[1, 17, 18, 20], [2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 6, 21], [2, 3, 7, 15], [2, 3, 8,
14], [2, 3, 9, 10], [2, 3, 11, 19], [2, 3, 12, 18], [2, 3, 13, 20], [2,
3, 16, 17], [2, 4, 7, 20], [2, 4, 8, 15], [2, 4, 9, 11], [2, 4, 10, 19],
[2, 4, 12, 17], [2, 4, 13, 14], [2, 4, 16, 18], [2, 5, 7, 14], [2, 5, 8,
20], [2, 5, 9, 12], [2, 5, 10, 18], [2, 5, 11, 17], [2, 5, 13, 15], [2,
5, 16, 19], [2, 6, 7, 18], [2, 6, 8, 19], [2, 6, 9, 13], [2, 6, 10, 17],
[2, 6, 11, 14], [2, 6, 12, 15], [2, 6, 16, 20], [2, 7, 8, 10], [2, 7,
11, 13], [2, 7, 12, 16], [2, 7, 19, 21], [2, 8, 11, 16], [2, 8, 12, 13],
[2, 8, 18, 21], [2, 9, 14, 19], [2, 9, 15, 18], [2, 9, 16, 21], [2, 9,
17, 20], [2, 10, 11, 12], [2, 10, 13, 16], [2, 10, 20, 21], [2, 11, 15,
21], [2, 12, 14, 21], [2, 13, 17, 21], [2, 14, 15, 17], [2, 14, 18, 20],
[2, 15, 19, 20], [2, 17, 18, 19], [3, 4, 7, 14], [3, 4, 8, 20], [3, 4,
9, 19], [3, 4, 10, 11], [3, 4, 12, 16], [3, 4, 13, 15], [3, 4, 17, 18],
[3, 5, 7, 20], [3, 5, 8, 15], [3, 5, 9, 18], [3, 5, 10, 12], [3, 5, 11,
16], [3, 5, 13, 14], [3, 5, 17, 19], [3, 6, 7, 19], [3, 6, 8, 18], [3,
6, 9, 16], [3, 6, 10, 13], [3, 6, 11, 15], [3, 6, 12, 14], [3, 6, 17,
20], [3, 7, 8, 9], [3, 7, 11, 17], [3, 7, 12, 13], [3, 7, 18, 21], [3,
8, 11, 13], [3, 8, 12, 17], [3, 8, 19, 21], [3, 9, 11, 12], [3, 9, 13,
17], [3, 9, 20, 21], [3, 10, 14, 18], [3, 10, 15, 19], [3, 10, 16, 20],
[3, 10, 17, 21], [3, 11, 14, 21], [3, 12, 15, 21], [3, 13, 16, 21], [3,
14, 15, 16], [3, 14, 19, 20], [3, 15, 18, 20], [3, 16, 18, 19], [4, 5,
6, 21], [4, 5, 7, 15], [4, 5, 8, 14], [4, 5, 9, 17], [4, 5, 10, 16], [4,
5, 11, 12], [4, 5, 13, 20], [4, 5, 18, 19], [4, 6, 7, 16], [4, 6, 8,
17], [4, 6, 9, 14], [4, 6, 10, 15], [4, 6, 11, 13], [4, 6, 12, 19], [4,
6, 18, 20], [4, 7, 8, 12], [4, 7, 9, 13], [4, 7, 10, 18], [4, 7, 17,
21], [4, 8, 9, 18], [4, 8, 10, 13], [4, 8, 16, 21], [4, 9, 10, 12], [4,
9, 15, 21], [4, 10, 14, 21], [4, 11, 14, 17], [4, 11, 15, 16], [4, 11,
18, 21], [4, 11, 19, 20], [4, 12, 13, 18], [4, 12, 20, 21], [4, 13, 19,
21], [4, 14, 15, 19], [4, 14, 16, 20], [4, 15, 17, 20], [4, 16, 17, 19],
[5, 6, 7, 17], [5, 6, 8, 16], [5, 6, 9, 15], [5, 6, 10, 14], [5, 6, 11,
18], [5, 6, 12, 13], [5, 6, 19, 20], [5, 7, 8, 11], [5, 7, 9, 19], [5,
7, 10, 13], [5, 7, 16, 21], [5, 8, 9, 13], [5, 8, 10, 19], [5, 8, 17,
21], [5, 9, 10, 11], [5, 9, 14, 21], [5, 10, 15, 21], [5, 11, 13, 19],
[5, 11, 20, 21], [5, 12, 14, 16], [5, 12, 15, 17], [5, 12, 18, 20], [5,
12, 19, 21], [5, 13, 18, 21], [5, 14, 15, 18], [5, 14, 17, 20], [5, 15,
16, 20], [5, 16, 17, 18], [6, 7, 8, 20], [6, 7, 9, 11], [6, 7, 10, 12],
[6, 7, 15, 21], [6, 8, 9, 12], [6, 8, 10, 11], [6, 8, 14, 21], [6, 9,
10, 20], [6, 9, 17, 21], [6, 10, 16, 21], [6, 11, 12, 20], [6, 11, 19,
21], [6, 12, 18, 21], [6, 13, 14, 15], [6, 13, 16, 17], [6, 13, 18, 19],
[6, 13, 20, 21], [6, 14, 16, 18], [6, 14, 17, 19], [6, 15, 16, 19], [6,
15, 17, 18], [7, 8, 13, 21], [7, 8, 14, 15], [7, 8, 16, 17], [7, 8, 18,
19], [7, 9, 12, 21], [7, 9, 14, 16], [7, 9, 15, 17], [7, 9, 18, 20], [7,
10, 11, 21], [7, 10, 14, 17], [7, 10, 15, 16], [7, 10, 19, 20], [7, 11,
14, 18], [7, 11, 15, 19], [7, 11, 16, 20], [7, 12, 14, 19], [7, 12, 15,
18], [7, 12, 17, 20], [7, 13, 14, 20], [7, 13, 16, 18], [7, 13, 17, 19],
[8, 9, 11, 21], [8, 9, 14, 17], [8, 9, 15, 16], [8, 9, 19, 20], [8, 10,
12, 21], [8, 10, 14, 16], [8, 10, 15, 17], [8, 10, 18, 20], [8, 11, 14,
19], [8, 11, 15, 18], [8, 11, 17, 20], [8, 12, 14, 18], [8, 12, 15, 19],
[8, 12, 16, 20], [8, 13, 15, 20], [8, 13, 16, 19], [8, 13, 17, 18], [9,
10, 13, 21], [9, 10, 14, 15], [9, 10, 16, 17], [9, 10, 18, 19], [9, 11,
14, 20], [9, 11, 16, 18], [9, 11, 17, 19], [9, 12, 15, 20], [9, 12, 16,
19], [9, 12, 17, 18], [9, 13, 14, 18], [9, 13, 15, 19], [9, 13, 16, 20],
[10, 11, 15, 20], [10, 11, 16, 19], [10, 11, 17, 18], [10, 12, 14, 20],
[10, 12, 16, 18], [10, 12, 17, 19], [10, 13, 14, 19], [10, 13, 15, 18],
[10, 13, 17, 20], [11, 12, 13, 21], [11, 12, 14, 15], [11, 12, 16, 17],
[11, 12, 18, 19], [11, 13, 14, 16], [11, 13, 15, 17], [11, 13, 18, 20],
[12, 13, 14, 17], [12, 13, 15, 16], [12, 13, 19, 20], [14, 15, 20, 21],
[14, 16, 19, 21], [14, 17, 18, 21], [15, 16, 18, 21], [15, 17, 19, 21],
[16, 17, 20, 21], [18, 19, 20, 21]]
```